# Распознавание лиц

Tags: распознавание-образов

С чего начать изучение такой проблематики, как распознавание лиц?

Вопрос достаточно абстрактный, но всё же?

Comment: Можно начать с изучения работы технологии, на которой базируется распознавание лиц — свёрточные 2D нейронные сети и их обучение. К примеру, вот видео для затравки, где объясняются собственно принципы: «[Teaching my computer to give me friends (I... I mean images!) (convolutional neural networks)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_7GWRup-nQ)».

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для начала с чтения [википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86).

Потом узнать, что в OpenCV эта задача уже [решена](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html?highlight=face#FaceRecognizer).

Можно ещё найти [сайт](http://face-rec.org/algorithms/) с описанием многих алгоритмов.

Comment: @KoVadim поправьте вторую ссылку.

Comment: а, если бы я хотел разобраться в теории, и сделать что-то примитивное самому?

Comment: Самому? Если сильно хочется, то:

 - почитайте в вики все по распознаванию образов.
 - научитесь распознавать линии/круги.
 - сделайте парочку распознавателей каптчей.
 - научитесь делать нейронные сети.

а потом будет понятно, как двигаться дальше. А ссылку на алгоритмы  я дал.

Answer (score 1):

[DLIB](http://dlib.net/) не так известен как OpenCV, но там эта задача решена еще лучше. кроме соссно распознавания лица (frontal face работает с показателем 87-89% против 73-75% в OpenCV) есть еще функция [Face Landmark Detection](http://www.learnopencv.com/facial-landmark-detection/)

Много там открытий чудных, захотите узнать больше то пищите ;-)

Comment: Eugene Bartosh добрый день! Очень интересна данная тема. Я сейчас хочу написать приложение для распознавания лиц в реальном времени и сравнение с фотографиями в БД. Не знаю что использовать, Open CV? Там из версии к версии меняется код библиотек. MS Oxford(но там триальный ключ для API), AForge - не знаю. Что можете порекомендовать и помочь в этом нелегком деле? Заранее спасибо!